# Ubuntu 20.04 just stopped reading my android device via usb

Tags: 20.04, usb, adb

I have an android device that I am using for debug purposes, I disconnected it and tried to reconnect it but It just stopped being read. my computer recognizes the devise for a split second then drops it immediately.

I am really lost on what's broken kindly help.

I installed ADB to see if I can see it listed but It doesn't either there.

Note: I connected the device to another computer(windows) and It works fine

Comment: Have you tested other USB devices in the same computer/port where you're having problems with the Android device? Do they work?

Comment: I have tested with another phone in all the ports its kinda the samething, It just connects for a split second then disconnects again  and again @ChanganAuto

Comment: OK, but still can be a software problem, something related to ADB, MPT/PTP or other. Other than phones, have you tested other devices, like a USB flash drive or external HDD/SSD?

Comment: not really, I shall try one later in the morning, I'll let you updated @ChanganAuto

Comment: Please, did you finally solved this? I am experiencing the same issue on Ubuntu 20. It usually worked without any problem, but sudenly it stoped working. No restarts on computer/device works, or enabling/dissabling usb debugging, or kill/restart adb server. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't able to find a reliable answer, but It usually work again when sleep the computer with the phone usb still plugged In and wake it back again. not an answer but it might help @gmanjon , check and leave a comment